# Challenging Linear Algebra Problem involving Vector Spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Problem:** Let $\{v_1,v_2,...v_n\}$ be a basis of a vector space $V$. Suppose $W$ is $k$ dimensional subspace of $V$ with $1<k<n$. Show that for any susbset $\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},...,v_{i_m}\}$ with $m>n-k$ there exists a nonzero vector $w\in W$ which is a linear combination of $\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},...,v_{i_m}\}.$

I am not quite convinced by the solution provided by the author. He first remarks that if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are two vector spaces then $\dim(W_1+W_2)<\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)$ implies that $W_1\cap W_2\not =\{0\}.$ Which makes sense. But then he says that since $n<m+k$ or $$\dim V<\dim W+\dim(\text{Span}(\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},...,v_{i_m}\}))$$ we have that there exists a $w\in W$ such that $w\in \text{Span}\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},...,v_{i_m}\}.$

Why is $V=W+\text{Span}\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},...,v_{i_m}\}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, $V = W + \text{span}\{v_{i_1},\ldots, v_{i_m}\}$ may be false. (For example, it is possible that $\text{span}\{v_{i_1},\ldots, v_{i_m}\} \subset W$.) But this is not what the author is implying.

The proof can be clarified by writing
$$\dim(W+\text{span}\{v_{i_1},\ldots, v_{i_m}\}) \le \dim(V) = n < m + k = \dim W + \dim \text{span}\{v_{i_1},\ldots, v_{i_m}\}.$$

Comment: Ok. That makes more sense. Thanks!